# How to override namespace argument in RedisAdapter for a Symfony4 app to cache

Tags: symfony, caching, redis, symfony4

I want to use custom namespace in our RedisAdapter to cache in our Symfony4 app. However, when i want to set arguments like this in our services.yaml;

```
cache.adapter.redis:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter
        arguments:
            - '@Redis'
            - 'app'
```

I see this error message:

**`Symfony\Component\Cache\Traits\RedisTrait::init() expects parameter 1 to be Redis, RedisArray, RedisCluster or Predis\ClientInterface, string given.`**

By the way, our cache config(config/packages/cache.yaml) is simple like below. So, how can I set namespace directly from any config?

```
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        default_redis_provider: 'redis://%env(REDIS_HOST)%:%env(REDIS_PORT)%'
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with this config:

```
app.cache.adapter.redis:
    parent: 'cache.adapter.redis'
    public: true
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: false
    tags:
        - {name: 'cache.pool', namespace: 'app'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the namespace to be interoperable with a third-party app,
you can take control over auto-generation by setting the `namespace` attribute of the `cache.pool` service tag.
For example, you can override the service definition of the adapter:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    app.cache.adapter.redis:
        parent: 'cache.adapter.redis'
        tags:
            - { name: 'cache.pool', namespace: 'my_custom_namespace' }
```

more details here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/12527

Comment: It looks like a dumb copy-paste of the official doc, except that this copy-paste will never be updated. Is this smart ?